# How to get MovieClip.prototype in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

In a ActionScript 2 code sample it uses some MovieClip.prototype's functions, as MovieClip.prototype.setModel;

I'm trying to write this example using an ActionScript 3 class, but the MoviewClip.prototype does not exists, where can I get it from? Does it exist in ActionScript 3?

**--update**

Ok, as you are asking, here goes, this code works just fine as an ActionScript included on frame1, but I want to make a ActionScript 3 class with this same code:

```
//package
//{
//  public class asteroids extends MovieClip
//  {

        var MW = 8;                     // Scaling factor for models (which were originally drawn on graph paper)
        var SW = Stage.width;           // Stage coords
        var SH = Stage.height;
        var kDegToRad = Math.PI/180;    // Useful constant for drawing circles & such
        var kDamp = 0.99;               // Damping in ship acceleration

        // The models
        //
        // Rocket fuselage
        var fuseModel = [{mx:0, my:-5.5, x:0, y:-4, pen:.5, clr:0x000033, alpha:50},
            {cx:-1,cy:-3,x:-1,y:-1, pen:2, clr:0x000033, alpha:50},
            {x:-.75,y:4},
            {cx:0, cy:4.5, x:.75,y:4},  // from -.75,4
            {x:1,y:-1},
            {cx:1,cy:-3,x:0,y:-4}];

        // Rocket fins
        var finModel = [ {mx:-1,my:-1,cx:-3,cy:4,x:-2,y:6,bf:0x0000FF,bfa:80},
            {cx:-1,cy:4.5,x:-.75,y:4}, 
            {x:-1,y:-1},
            {mx:.75,my:4,cx:1,cy:4.5,x:2,y:6},
            {cx:3,cy:4,x:1,y:-1},
            {x:.75,y:4,ef:1}
        ];

        // Routine to scale model to arbitrary size
        function scaleModel(m,s)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < m.length; ++i)
            {
                var pt = m[i];
                if (pt.mx != undefined)
                {
                    pt.mx *= s;
                    pt.my *= s;
                }
                if (pt.cx != undefined)
                {
                    pt.cx *= s;
                    pt.cy *= s;
                }
                pt.x *= s;
                pt.y *= s;
            }
        }

        // Draw a model
        //
        function drawModel(m)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < m.length; ++i) 
            {
                var pt = m[i];
                if (pt.bf != undefined)
                    this.beginFill(pt.bf, pt.bfa);
                if (pt.pen != undefined)
                    this.lineStyle(pt.pen,pt.clr,pt.alpha);
                if (pt.mx != undefined)
                    this.moveTo(pt.mx,pt.my);
                if (pt.cx != undefined)
                    this.curveTo(pt.cx,pt.cy,pt.x,pt.y);
                else if (pt.x != undefined)
                    this.lineTo(pt.x,pt.y);
                if (pt.ef != undefined)
                    this.endFill();
            }
        }


        // Ship Movement and most game-play stuff happens here
        function ShipMove()
        {

            // Steering & Thrust
            if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT))
                this._rotation -= 5;
            else if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT))
                this._rotation += 5;
            if (Key.isDown(Key.CONTROL) || Key.isDown(Key.UP))
            {
                this.vx += Math.sin(this._rotation*kDegToRad);
                this.vy -= Math.cos(this._rotation*kDegToRad);
            }
            else if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)) 
            {
                this.vx *= .9;
                this.vy *= .9;
            }
            // Basic movement with acceleration and damping
            this._x += this.vx;
            this._y += this.vy;

            // Wrap around edges of stage
            if (this._x < -this._width)
                this._x += SW+this._width*2;
            else if (this._x > SW+this._width)
                this._x -= SW+this._width*2;
            if (this._y < -this._height)
                this._y += SH+this._height*2;
            else if (this._y > SH+this._height)
                this._y -= SH+this._height*2;

        }


        // Initialize new ship
        function NewShip()
        {
            ship_mc._x = SW/2;
            ship_mc._y = SH/2;
            ship_mc.onEnterFrame = shipMove;
        }

        // Assign a sprite model to a movieclip & draw it
        //
        MovieClip.prototype.setModel = function(m)
        {
            this.model = m;
            this.drawModel(m);
        }

        MovieClip.prototype.drawModel = drawModel;

        scaleModel(fuseModel, MW*.8); // Using a slightly smaller rocket than original drawing
        scaleModel(finModel, MW*.8);

        // One Time Initialziation
        //
        _root.createEmptyMovieClip("ship_mc", 2);
        ship_mc.createEmptyMovieClip("fuselage", 1);
        ship_mc.fuselage.setModel(fuseModel);
        ship_mc.createEmptyMovieClip("fins", 2);
        ship_mc.fins.setModel(finModel);

        NewShip();

//  }
//}
```

Comment: Can you describe more about what you want to do? There's a sort of prototype-like thing in the guts of AS3, but it's not usually a very helpful thing to mess with. Usually you want to subclass MovieClip and decorate or override stuff, but if you comment on your goals we can be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably extend MovieClip and add the new functionality to the subclass, it's the best/proper way to go. Prototypes in AS2 are old, and were used when the language didn't support true OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Using prototypes in AS3 is discouraged.
But there is a way to use it if you are compiling AS3 with the flex compiler.

First, you need to give a few compiler options.

PrototypeExtension-config.xml

```
<flex-config>
    <compiler>
       <as3>false</as3>
       <es>true</es>
       <strict>false</strict>
    </compiler>
</flex-config>
```

PrototypeExtension.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class PrototypeExtension extends Sprite {
        public function PrototypeExtension() {
            stage.align = "tl";
            stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
            MovieClip.prototype.move = function (x:int, y:int):void {
                this.x = x; this.y = y;
            };
            MovieClip.prototype.tween = function (to:Point, duration:int):void {
                var start:int = getTimer();
                var from:Point = new Point(this.x, this.y);
                var thisInstance:MovieClip = this;
                this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function tweener(e:Event):void {
                    var time:int = getTimer() - start;

                    if (time > duration) {
                        thisInstance.move(to.x, to.y);
                        thisInstance.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tweener);
                    }
                    var t:Number = time / duration;
                    t = t * (2 - t);
                    var u:Number = 1 - t;
                    thisInstance.move(u * from.x + t * to.x, u * from.y + t *to.y);
                });

            }
            var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
            mc.graphics.beginFill(0);
            mc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
            mc.graphics.endFill();
            mc.tween(new Point(400, 300), 1000);
            addChild(mc);
        }
    }
}
```

by

mxmlc PrototypeExtension.as

You can see how prototype extension is enabled in AS3.